# Unsupported type UNION error in CDF Pipeline with BigQuery Sink

Tags: json, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a parametrized pipeline in Cloud Data Fusion that gives me the following error:

I'll post pictures of the pipeline and the details of the bigquery sinks that are giving me problems, I have no idea what's going on, the schema of the view in bigquery makes perfect sense and the data types are appropiately converted to those data fusion needs.

```
Schema of my view in BQ (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oygbD.png)
Pipeline (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiQnc.png)
tmp_scd2 info (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC0d1.png)
```

I have been toying with preview mode and have found that the BigQuery sink is the problem, if I put a trash sink instead it works, but when I put the appropiate BigQuery sink it doesn't. I have tried using the schema as a parameter and not using it as a parameter because maybe I did something wrong when converting it  and using the http calls but it doesn't make a difference.

I have tried to find a problem with the schema i am importing, which is here, along with the other parameters:

```
{
"output_schema":"{"name":"etlSchemaBody","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"src_sys_id","type":"long"},{"name":"src_sys_cd","type":"string"},{"name":"src_sys_nmcz","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_nmen","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_dsccz","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_dscen","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"srt_seq","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"upd_dttm","type":[{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"}]},{"name":"end_dttm","type":[{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"}]},{"name":"start_dttm","type":[{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"}]},{"name":"hist_type","type":"long"}]}",



"source_dataset": "xxx",

"compute_project": "xxxx",

"dataset_project": "xxxb",

"temporary_dataset":"xxxx",

"input_schema":"{"name":"etlSchemaBody","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"src_sys_id","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_cd","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_nmcz","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_nmen","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_dsccz","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"src_sys_dscen","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"srt_seq","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"upd_dttm","type":[{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"},"null"]},{"name":"start_dttm","type":[{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"},"null"]},{"name":"hist_type","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"active_flag","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"mapping_name","type":["string","null"]}]}",

"condition_dq": "(src_sys_id !~ -2 && src_sys_id != -9)", 

"temporary_bucket": "xxx",

"source_table": "vw_src_sys",
"date_of_load": "20221030",

"target_table": "src_sys",

"output_schema_blacklist": "upd_dttm,end_dttm",

"output_column_list":"src_sys_id,start_dttm,end_dttm,src_sys_cd,src_sys_nmcz,src_sys_nmen,src_sys_type_dsccz,src_sys_dscen,srt_seq,upd_dttm,hist_type",

"output_schema_joinkeys": "src_sys_id,start_dttm, hist_type",

"target_dataset": "vxz"

}
```